# Solving electrical network in Python

Tags: circuit-analysis, python

I have a complicated electrical network. I would like to calculate voltage drop across across the network i.e. nodes 2-15, given V1=10 V and V16=0 V. The values of the resistances are known.

Is there a Python package which can calculate? I can write equation for each node using Ohm's and Kirchoff's laws, but then manually solving 14 linear equations simultaneously is tedious.

[image]

Comment: [SymPy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) (note the Py at the end?) does this just fine and it can do it, symbolically. Though you can use Sage or Sympy to also solve it numerically. Finally, this is trivial to solve numerically using partials at each node and using an iterative loop until all the node voltages settle down. For example, [like this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/397805/38098) or [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/342358/38098)

Comment: solving 14 linear equations manually is tedious, but solving them automatically with Numpy is much easier, and the way that SPICE would go about completing your problem. I forget the exact notation, but having formed up the equations Ax = B, you write x =B/A, and Numpy figures out the rest.

Comment: If you can generate the "netlist" automatically for some arbitrary software package, why not do it for a SPICE engine, which is specifically designed to solve these sort of problems? SPICE netlists should be recognized by many SPICE softwares (LTspice, MicroCap, Ngspice, to name a few free ones). Symbolic and/or numeric solving such circuits with other software may come at a cost, depending on the complexity, whereas SPICE does it natively.

Answer (score 1):

For sloving simple circuits in python I use [pySpice](https://pyspice.fabrice-salvaire.fr/releases/v1.5/) library. There you have simple example with resistors: [link](https://pyspice.fabrice-salvaire.fr/releases/v1.5/examples/resistor/voltage-divider.html).

Second link shows example circuit definition for two resistors. By expanding this example you can recreate your own circuit.

Answer (score 1):

I'll follow the algorithm and benchmark problem from [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/342358/10810).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhWvxk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The code is dirty and does the job. It could be much improved, but I had no time to further mess with it.

```python
import random

class Item:
    def __new__(cls, n: int):
        if n in cls.all:
            return cls.all[n]
        item = super().__new__(cls)
        item.n = n
        cls.all[n] = item
        return item


class Node(Item):
    all = {}
    
    def __init__(self, n: int):
        super().__init__()
        if not hasattr(self, 'elements'):
            self.elements = {}
            self.adjacentNodes = {}
            self.adjacentElements = {} # indexed by nodes
        
    def __iadd__(self, *elements):
        for el in elements:
            assert isinstance(el, Element)
            el.addNode(self)
            self.elements[el.n] = el
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.__class__.__name__}({self.n})"


class Element(Item):
    nmax = 0
    all = {}

    @staticmethod
    def newNumber():
        Element.nmax += 1
        return Element.nmax
    
    def __new__(cls, *nodeNumbers, n: int|None=None, **kwargs):
        return super().__new__(cls, n or Element.newNumber())
        
    def __init__(self, *nodeNumbers, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        if not hasattr(self, 'nodes'):
            self.nodes = set()
            nodes = [Node(n) for n in nodeNumbers]
            for node in nodes:
                node += self
            assert len(nodes) in [0,2]
            if nodes:
                nodes[0].adjacentNodes[nodes[1].n] = nodes[1]
                nodes[0].adjacentElements[nodes[1].n] = self
                nodes[1].adjacentNodes[nodes[0].n] = nodes[0]
                nodes[1].adjacentElements[nodes[0].n] = self
            return True
        return False

    def addNode(self, node):
        self.nodes.add(node)


class R(Element):
    def __init__(self, *args, r=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if not hasattr(self, 'r'):
            if r is None:
                r = R.randomResistance()
            self.r = r
    
    @staticmethod
    def randomResistance(min=0.1, max=1E3):
        return min + random.betavariate(alpha=2, beta=5)*max

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.__class__.__name__}({self.n}: r={self.r} {self.nodes})"

# define the problem

if 0:
    # The problem from the question
    R(1, 2), R(2, 3), R(1, 4), R(2, 5), R(3, 6)
    R(4, 5), R(5, 6), R(4, 7), R(5, 8), R(6, 9)
    R(7, 8), R(8, 9), R(9, 10), R(8, 11), R(9, 12), R(10, 13)
    R(11, 12), R(12, 13), R(11, 14), R(12, 15), R(13, 16)
    Node(1).V = 10
    Node(16).V = 0
else:
    # The benchmark problem
    R(1, 2, n=7, r=5), R(2, 3, n=8, r=21)
    R(1, 4, n=1, r=61), R(2, 5, n=2, r=50), R(3, 6, n=3, r=16)
    R(4, 5, n=10, r=76), R(5, 6, n=9, r=10)
    R(4, 7, n=4, r=56), R(5, 8, n=5, r=45), R(6, 9, n=6, r=18)
    R(7, 8, n=11, r=32), R(8, 9, n=12, r=22)
    Node(4).V = 0
    Node(6).V = 1
    
# determine the parallel resistance of attached resistors

for node in Node.all.values():
    rpar = 0
    for el in node.elements.values():
        rpar += 1/el.r
    node.rpar = 1/rpar

# determine the computation order

nodeOrder = []
nodes = {}
for n, node in Node.all.items():
    if not hasattr(node, 'V'):
        nodes[n] = node
while nodes:
    remove = set()
    for node in nodes.values():
        for el in node.elements.values():
            for depnode in el.nodes:
                remove.add(depnode.n)
        remove.remove(node.n)
    group = list(set(nodes.keys()) - remove)
    assert group
    nodeOrder += group
    for done in group:
        del nodes[done]
assert not nodes

# preset node potentials
for node in Node.all.values():
    if not hasattr(node, 'V'):
        node.V = 0

# update node potentials
nodeOrder = [Node(n) for n in nodeOrder]
for i in range(0, 100):
    for node in nodeOrder:
        V = 0
        for adjNode in node.adjacentNodes.values():
            V += adjNode.V/node.adjacentElements[adjNode.n].r
        node.V = V*node.rpar

for n in Node.all.values():
    print(n.V)
```

The node voltages for the benchmark problem are, in order 1-9:

```
>>> %Run rsolver.py
0.6517578962898488
0.7051806746742627
0.8725105620201647
0
0.8410039648620072
1
0.47455268117334604
0.7457256418438295
0.8855765388295932
```

They match with the CircuitLab simulation results.